# app.config in nunit test for acceptance testing

Tags: nunit, specflow

I have written some specflow tests. To get those test to run I need to configure some parts in App.config. Running the test with resharper as test runner in visual studio it works perfectly fine, but when running the test with the NUnit test runner it seems like the App.config is not read and all tests that depends on it fails (in my case that is every test).

Is there possible to get the NUnit test runner to read the app.config specified for a .dll?

**UPDATE:** I'm using the 2.5.10 version of NUnit.

My app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityMappingsConfiguration" type="OPF.KP.Business.EntitySettings, OPF.KP.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
  </configSections>
  <entityMappingsConfiguration>
    <entityMappings>
      <entityMapping entityShortTypeName="ValidationResult" entityFactoryFullTypeName="OPF.KP.Business.Tests.ValidationResultStubFactory, OPF.KP.Business.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <entityMapping entityShortTypeName="Stillingsmelding" entityFactoryFullTypeName="OPF.KP.Business.FitNesseTests.StillingsmeldingFitNesseStubFactory, OPF.KP.Business.FitNesseTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <entityMapping entityShortTypeName="Stillingsmeldingsfelter" entityFactoryFullTypeName="OPF.KP.Business.StillingsmeldingsfelterFactory, OPF.KP.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <entityMapping entityShortTypeName="IInputModeSettings" entityFactoryFullTypeName="OPF.KP.Business.Tests.SettingsStubFactory, OPF.KP.Business.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </entityMappings>
  </entityMappingsConfiguration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ShouldExecuteHistoricValidation" value="true" />
    <add key="Kontrollstasjon.ValidatorService.Validate.ExecuteNoEnhetDuplicationVerification" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <specFlow>
    <language feature="no" />
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your app.config?

Comment: I'm not sure how that will help you, if there was an error in the app.config and it would be read I would get a different kind of runtime error. My problem is that is that the config file is not read at all. But I've updated with the config I used.